# WPF dynamic treeview with checkbox, data from SQL Server

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, treeview

I want to build a dynamic treeview with checkboxes from database for build a dynamic menu permission for different user’s level. The checkboxes will bind with values and keys. Those checkboxes will show the text and when its checked and saved, I will be able to get the correspond IDs from those checkboxes.

If someone please help me ?

**Data in the tables**

> ```
> Menu Header TableA : Here Menu TableA has ID: TableA
> ID:   SubMenuHeader:
> A1    TableA1
> A2    TableA2
> A3    TableA3
>
> Menu TableB : Here Menu TableB has ID: TableB
> ID:   SubMenuHeader:
> B1    TableB1
> B2    TableB2
> B3    TableB3
>
> TableA1
> ID:   SubSubMenuHeader:   RefMenuTable_ID:
> C1    TableC1             A1
> C2    TableC2             A1
> C3    TableC3             A1
> ```

**The tree should looks like: please imagine the dot (*) as Checkbox**

- TableA

  - TableA1

    - TableC1
    - TableC2
    - TableC3
  - TableA2
  - TableA3
- TableB

  - TableB1
  - TableB2
  - TableB3

Thanks in advance !

Comment: i need same requirement . can you please share your solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to build an observable data structure of the hierarchy and then bind it to the tree and specify the HierarchialDataTemplate to resolve the nested bindings.

I'm probably define something like:

```
class ItemClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  public bool IsChecked
  public string Header
  ObservableCollection<ItemClass> Children;
}
```

Then just build up an `ObservableCollection<ItemClass> Items` and populate it up from the database. Bind that to the TreeView's ItemsSource, specify the HierarchialDataTemplate and the control template for the TreeViewItem and bind up IsChecked and Header. The HierarchialDataTemplate will tell the TreeView how to recurse through your objects.

Comment: I m new in WPF, can you please provide more elborate code?

Comment: i need same requirement . can you please share your solution